# Emailing uploaded file from html form with PHP

Tags: php, html, wordpress, file

I just finished an HTML form for one of my wordpress sites, and it works great. When it's submitted it creates the person as a user in the WP_User database table and it sends me an email with all of the info from the form. However, my html form allows the user to upload a required file but the email only shows the file name. I'm looking for a way to email the actual file to be viewed and downloaded. Here's my code thus far:

```
    <div id="container">
    <form method="post" name="myForm">
    <h1 align="center">Welcome!</h1>
    <h2 align="center">Thank you for your interest. We look forward to working with you.</h2>
    <h3>First Name</h3> <input type="text" name="fName" style="width: 355px;"/>
    <h3>Last Name</h3> <input type="text" name="lName" style="width: 355px;"/>
   <h3>Company Name</h3> <input type="text" name="compName" style="width: 355px;"/>
   <h3>Business Needs</h3> 
   <select name="businessNeeds" style="width: 355px;">
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="IntDesign">Interior Designer</option>
    <option value="Ecom">E-Commerce Only</option>
    <option value="Retail">Retail Store Only</option>
    <option value="RetailEcom">Retail and E-Commerce</option>
    <option value="Mult">Multiple Locations</option>
  </select>
   <h3>Address</h3> <input type="text"  name="address" style="width: 355px;"/>
   <h3>City</h3> <input type="text"  name="city"  style="width: 355px;"/>
   <h3>State</h3> <input type="text"  name="state"  style="width: 355px;"/>
   <h3>Zip</h3> <input type="text"  name="zip" style="width: 355px;"/>
   <h3>Phone</h3> <input type="text"  name="phone" style="width: 355px;"/>
    <h3>Email</h3>  <input id="email" type="text" name="uemail" style="width: 355px;"/>
    <h3>Create a Username</h3> <input type="text"  name="uname" style="width: 355px;"/>
    <h3>Create a Password</h3> <input type="password"  name="pass" style="width: 355px;"/>
    <h3>Confirm Password</h3> <input type="password"  name="ConfPass" style="width: 355px;"/>
    <h3>Sales Tax ID</h3> <input type="text" name="taxID" style="width: 355px;"/>
    <h3>Upload Tax ID Certificate</h3> <input type="file" name="fileUpload" style="width: 355px;"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</div>


<?php
function create_account(){

$fName = ( isset($_POST['fName']) ? $_POST['fName'] : '' );
$lName = ( isset($_POST['lName']) ? $_POST['lName'] : '' );
$compName = ( isset($_POST['compName']) ? $_POST['compName'] : '' );
$businessNeeds = ( isset($_POST['businessNeeds']) ? $_POST['businessNeeds'] : '' );
$address = ( isset($_POST['address']) ? $_POST['address'] : '' );
$city = ( isset($_POST['city']) ? $_POST['city'] : '' );
$state = ( isset($_POST['state']) ? $_POST['state'] : '' );
$zip = ( isset($_POST['zip']) ? $_POST['zip'] : '' );
$phone = ( isset($_POST['phone']) ? $_POST['phone'] : '' );
$email = ( isset($_POST['uemail']) ? $_POST['uemail'] : '' );
$user = ( isset($_POST['uname']) ? $_POST['uname'] : '' );
$pass = ( isset($_POST['upass']) ? $_POST['upass'] : '' );
$ConfPass = ( isset($_POST['ConfPass']) ? $_POST['ConfPass'] : '' );
$taxID = ( isset($_POST['taxID']) ? $_POST['taxID'] : '' );
$fileUpload = ( isset($_POST['fileUpload']) ? $_POST['fileUpload'] : '' );

$email_from = 'admin';
$email_subject = "New Wholesale Form Submission";
$message = "You have received a new message from: \n";
$message .= "First Name: " .$_POST["fName"]. "\n";                            
$message .= "Last Name: ".$_POST["lName"]. "\n";
$message .= "Company Name: ".$_POST["compName"]. "\n";
$message .= "Business Type: " .$_POST["businessNeeds"]. "\n";
$message .= "Address: ".$_POST["address"]. "\n";
$message .= "City: ".$_POST["city"]. "\n";
$message .= "State: ".$_POST["state"]. "\n";
$message .= "Zip: ".$_POST["zip"]. "\n";
$message .= "Phone: ".$_POST["phone"]. "\n";
$message .= "Email: ".$_POST["uemail"]. "\n";
$message .= "Tax ID: ".$_POST["taxID"]. "\n";
$message .= "Certificate: ".$_POST["fileUpload"]. "\n";


$to = "email";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";



if ( !username_exists( $user )  && !email_exists( $email ) ) {
   $user_id = wp_create_user( $user, $pass, $email );
   if( !is_wp_error($user_id) ) {
       //user has been created
       $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
       $user->set_role( 'subscriber' ); 


       wp_mail( $to, $email_subject, $message, $headers );


       //Redirect
       wp_redirect( 'URL' );
       exit;
   } else {
       //$user_id is a WP_Error object. Manage the error
   }
}

}
add_action('init','create_account');
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/#comment-345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form tag

The enctype property sets or returns the value of the enctype attribute in a form.

The enctype attribute specifies how form-data should be encoded before sending it to the server.

The form-data is encoded to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" by default. This means that all characters are encoded before they are sent to the server (spaces are converted to "+" symbols, and special characters are converted to ASCII HEX values).

in multipart/form-data  No characters are encoded. This value is required when you are using forms that have a file upload control

Comment: Thank you, I think I'm on the right track. I put that in my form tag before method, as stated on the PHP manual site, and now when I get the email the file name is gone, but it's blank so there is no link there to open or download the file. SHould anything be added to PHP directly?

Comment: you have to upload file on your server then mail user the link of that file see here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_file_uploading.htm

Comment: Ah, I thought it could send directly. I will work on that script, thank you!